# Shiny formatting for lm.summary

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to include a model summary in a shiny page using renderPrint; the code looks like:

```
# server.R
shinyServer( function(input, output) {
  output$modelSummary <- renderPrint(
    summary(model())
  )
})

# ui.R
fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    mainPanel(textOutput(outputId = "modelSummary"))
  )
)
```

`model()` is a very simple `lm` model stored in a reactive variable.

The output looks (both on my OS X and Win machines) like this:

[image: Capture]

I see two problems:

- no end of lines
- the  tags next to the stars

How can I get the same clean print output as in the R console?

I run R 3.2.2 and shiny 0.12.2.

Comment: Use `verbatimTextOutput` instead of `textOutput`.

Comment: Aha! It kind of solves my issues (although text is now embedded in a grey box, but I can live with that). However the <U+0091> thingies are still here - looks like some encoding issue. Any idea wrt these?

Comment: That's a new one to me.  sorry.